# Loosing category link when saving product (at store level)

Tags: magento-1.7, product

So, I'm getting a product collection for a store, affecting a data change and saving the product:

```
Mage::app('english', 'store');
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setStore('english'); // clarity, you cannot actually influence it
foreach($products AS $product)
{
    $product->setName($product->getName(). ' '); // add space to trigger hasDataChange
    $product->save();
}
```

After this loop, my entire catalog/product association is gone for all storeviews (indexes are on UPDATE, but even then - a reindex does not help).

What's the cause of this and how should I do it instead? It's imperative that I get the collection for a user-specified store, so I can't do `Mage::app('admin')` in my script.

Note: this is a 1.7.0.0 installation (due for upgrade).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never call save unless you have a new instance of the product model or if you called load before.
The products model instances that come from a collection do not contain all the necessary data from the db.
When a save is done you get strange results...like losing data.

So for updating a product you either call `load` then `setWhatEver` then `save` or you use `updateAttributes`.
Calling `load` and `save` in a loop is bad practice, but if you plan to run it only once it could work.
The alternative is to use the `updateAttributes` method when you have only a few values to update

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    $productIds, //array with product ids to update
    array('name'=>'New name', 'description'=>'New description'), //array with attributes to update. THey are all added to all the products from the previous param
    0, //store id. 0 for 'default values'
);
```

So I guess your script should look like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setStore('english'); // clarity, you cannot actually influence it
foreach($products AS $product)
{
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        array($product->getId()),
        array('name'=>$product->getName(). ' '), //append a space to the name
        0,
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. For completeness, I did try with a full load within the loop, but I still lost the category/product link. Verifying if this works, cause I need the `catalog_product_save_commit_after` to fire.

Comment: I got more work to do in the observer part, but this is the key to not loosing the linked table information. Thanks again, Marius.